# Uniqueness of distance realizing geodesic in hyperbolic surface.

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hyperbolic surfaces](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/95640/hyperbolic-surfaces)

Given a hyperbolic surface S with geodesic boundary. Let  a and b be two distinct simple closed geodesic boundaries. Does there exist a unique distance realizing geodesic in S?
 (1) for  S is a pair of pants. 
(2) S is any hyperbolic surface with boundary.

Comment: If you want to refine your question, you should edit the first one.  There is an "edit" link below the tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the pants, yes.  In general, no.  To prove this for the pants, classify *all* geodesic arcs and just observe the result.  There are many ways to find a "no" example in the general case; the first one that came to my mind was taking a double cover.

EDIT - I see that this is a near-duplicate of a closed question.  You could improve your question by giving some motivation.  Reading the FAQ will be very useful in writing questions that get good answers.  In particular please see https://mathoverflow.net/faq#whatnot

Comment: well, I have got an example of hyperbolic surface with boundary where more than one (at least two) distance realizing geodesics between two distinct geodesic boundaries will exist. I have a further question: Suppose p and q are two distance realizing geodesics between the boundary geodesics. Is it true that p and q are always disjoint?     

Comment: They are always disjoint.  This is proved by the usual "exchange and round-off" technique.  See, if $p$ and $q$ intersect, then at the intersection point you can do a little cut and paste to get two new arcs $p'$ and $q'$, still connecting the same boundary components, and slightly shorter, which is a contradiction.